# Dictionary in Azure Configuration Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, appsettings

I have a sample application in .NET core, the appsettings.json file is used to store the configurations.

In this json file I created a hierarchy to be transformed into a Dictionary<string, string> to be accessed from some methods in my code.

All works correctly and no problems until here.

Now, this app is hosted in Azure, and I am migrating all my settings into Azure Configuration - Application settings section.

[image]

The appsettings values in first level work correctly in Azure settings section (for example: SampleSettingAddress).

Would you know how a dictionary (OptionsDictionary, MusicUrls) should be placed in Azure settings fields? Is it possible?

```
     "SampleSetting": {
    
        "SampleSettingAddress": "sample",
    
        "SampleSettingEmailAddress": "sample",
    
     
    
        "MusicUrls": {
    
          "musicStore": "https://samplemusic1.com/hits/",
    
          "musicStoreAn": "https://samplemusic2.com/hits/",
    
          "musicStoreExt": "https://samplemusic3.com/hits/"
    
        },
    
        "OptionsDictionary": {
    
          "key1": "sample1",
    
          "key2": "sample2",
    
          "key3": "sample3"
    
        }
    
    }

 

 

public class SampleSetting

    {

        public string SampleSettingAddress { get; set; }

 

        public string SampleSettingEmailAddress { get; set; }

 

        public Dictionary<string, string> MusicUrls { get; set; }

                              

        public Dictionary<string, string> OptionsDictionary { get; set; }

                              

   }

 

    "SampleSetting": {
    
        "SampleSettingAddress": "sample",
    
        "SampleSettingEmailAddress": "sample",
    
     
    
        "MusicUrls": {
    
          "musicStore": "https://samplemusic1.com/hits/",
    
          "musicStoreAn": "https://samplemusic2.com/hits/",
    
          "musicStoreExt": "https://samplemusic3.com/hits/"
    
        },
    
        "OptionsDictionary": {
    
          "key1": "sample1",
    
          "key2": "sample2",
    
          "key3": "sample3"
    
        }
    
    }

 

 

public class SampleSetting

    {

        public string SampleSettingAddress { get; set; }

 

        public string SampleSettingEmailAddress { get; set; }

 

        public Dictionary<string, string> MusicUrls { get; set; }

                              

        public Dictionary<string, string> OptionsDictionary { get; set; }

                              

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is certainly possible to do so. This is how you would do it:

```
Name: SampleSetting__SampleSettingAddress
Value: sample

Name: SampleSetting__MusicUrls__musicStore
Value: https://samplemusic1.com/hits/
```

Basically you will need to flatten your JSON object and use `__` as kind of delimiter. If you're on Windows, you can also use `:` instead of `__`.